# Event Attendees search bar can´t show users

Tags: lightning-community, event

Original question - https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000lFXiQAM. I have the same issue with selecting users in the Attendees search bar when creating an event. I log in as a community user (Customer Community Plus) and try to create a new event and invite users from the same community. The main goal is that those users should see this event in their calendars. But I cannot select user records. I only see their corresponding contacts.

[image]

This user can see other users in the community. When I search for other users in the Assigned To field, other users are shown.

[image]

The admin user can see both the contact and user records.

[image]

Does anybody know what's going wrong with the Attendees search bar?

Comment: the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_calendar_attendees.htm) for this say "set up sales reps to add salesforce users...etc". Have you tested on a non-admin and non-community user to see if it's specific to the type of user?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, i don't know your settings or profiles, but looks to be just related to chatter or profile access for the users in the community.

[image]
1. [Search Behavior in Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_search_behavior.htm&type=5)

[image]
2. [Who Can See What in Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_visibility.htm&type=5)